# Start closing "I can't see partitions while installing" questions

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I have seen a lot (really tons of them) questions regarding *"I can't see [Windows] partitions while installing Ubuntu"*.

A common property between all of them is that almost none of them has *close votes* for **bug**. Why??? It should be closed as such because .. it is a bug!

Also some of them provide more information that others, but that is not relevant (IMO).

So the thing is, lets close them, and if someone has/found a workaround lets link them as dupe!

---

Here are *some* of them, but is easy to find more:

- https://askubuntu.com/q/417409/62483
- [Ubuntu can't see windows 7 partition when installing 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/332801/62483)
- [Ubuntu 12.04 can't see Windows 7](https://askubuntu.com/q/298382/62483)
- [Why doesn't Ubuntu 12.04 recognize my Windows 7 partition?](https://askubuntu.com/q/265132/62483)
- [I can't see my partitions to install ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/252414/62483)

Comment: I remember that I made a canonical answer about the most possible reasons and gave the question a proper title... let me look for it.

Comment: @Braiam that would be great. If you found it, create an answer.

Comment: [Here's one](http://askubuntu.com/q/371783/169736), then another [that essentially says the same](http://askubuntu.com/questions/331172/ubuntu-will-not-install-alongside-windows-no-option/).

Comment: *Is* it a bug though? Is this not a remnant of an improper Windows shutdown? This should be duped over and over and over again.